# Quality title ctype_alnum and not so common letters?

Tags: php

So the function ctype_alnum doesn't recognize characters such as õäöü as alphanumeric, even though they are. Is it a fixed set of characters its checking against? Can I change it to be more inclusive of other alphabets and not just english?

Comment: a) Are those characters utf-8 encoded? b) What does `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL,"0"));` print on your system?

Comment: @VolkerK The file is utf-8 encoded and has header('charset=utf-8');, that command prints string(1) "C"

Comment: @user81993: Please include this information in your question and then mark your comment as 'obsolete'.

Comment: Please search SO for `php ctype utf-8`.